# Why does this function stub not work using cl-letf?

Tags: common-lisp, ert

I have written this simple function and I want to stub out the last functions so I don't actually launch a process.

```el
(defun dc-test-stub-process (command &rest params)
  (interactive)
  (let ((commands (append (list dc-buffer-name dc-docker-cmd command) params)))
    (apply #'dc-process commands)))
```

I have been playing around with this expecting it to fail because it returns `"test"` how ever it just passes and it looks like `dc-process` is actually called and not stubbed out.

```el
(ert-deftest pp-test-process-function ()
  (setq dc-current-buffer "/")
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'dc-process)
             (lambda (&rest _) "test"))
    (should (equal (dc-test-stub-process "a" "d" "c") "test2")))))
```

I have also tried doing the same but stubbing out `apply` with the same results.

Anyone able to spot what's wrong? There is not much info on using `cl-letf` but most likely I am doing something wrong as I am still learning lisp.

Comment: Hint: try indenting your code with `C-M-\ `

Comment: I did not know about that shortcut although i says indented my highlighted region and nothing actually changes, so i guess it likes the indent ? it does tend to auto indent as I hit return.

Comment: Did you highlight the whole thing? You have a paren in the wrong place, indenting should definitely make changes that will it more obvious.

Comment: not sure whats happening, if i change the indent level and the do C-M-\ it restores the indent to how it was previous so my emacs thinks its correct for some reason :/

Comment: your exactly right on the paren, i have it working but now i want to know why my indent does not work or if there is some kind of reformat my code function i can use.

Comment: What emacs version do you have? If you do `emacs -Q` and then paste the code in `*scratch*` does it also indent the same way?

Comment: same behavior, i have just noticed it does adjust by a single space which i had not noticed I am using emacs 25.1.1 perhaps thats all its supposed to do i was expecting something more drastic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indent your code, you should end up with the following:

```el
(ert-deftest pp-test-process-function ()
  (setq dc-current-buffer "/")
  (cl-letf
      (((symbol-function 'dc-process)
        (lambda (&rest params) "test"))
       (should (equal (dc-test-stub-process "a" "d" "c") "test2")))))
```

Which should make clear that you are actually binding a variable called `should` to the result of `(equal (dc-test-stub-process "a" "d" "c") "test2")`.  Since you use `cl-letf` and not `cl-letf*`, the binding for `(symbol-function 'dc-process)` is not in effect during the next binding.

It can be even more obvious if you put the put first binding on the same line as the `cl-letf`:

```el
(ert-deftest pp-test-process-function ()
  (setq dc-current-buffer "/")
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'dc-process)
             (lambda (&rest params) "test"))
            (should (equal (dc-test-stub-process "a" "d" "c") "test2")))))
```

Correcting the parentheses so that you end up with your original indentation should give the expected behaviour, i.e., that `(should (equal ...))` is the body of the `cl-letf` so it runs with the `dc-process` binding in effect:

```el
(ert-deftest pp-test-process-function ()
  (setq dc-current-buffer "/")
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'dc-process)
             (lambda (&rest params) "test")))
    (should (equal (dc-test-stub-process "a" "d" "c") "test2"))))
```

Comment: thanks for the assistance I will reformat with your suggestions :)